# The probability of choosing $j$ balls

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have 9 balls that can be chosen with independent probabilities $p_1 = \frac{1}{10}, p_2 = \frac{2}{10}, p_3 = \frac{3}{10}, p_4 = \frac{1}{10}, p_5 = 0, p_6 = \frac{1}{2}, p_7 = \frac{1}{10}, p_8 = 0, p_9 = \frac{2}{10}$, where $p_i$ is the probability with which the $i$th ball can be cosen.

I can't calculate the probability of choosing $j$ balls, where $0 \le j \le 9$ is arbitrary. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: I don't see an easier way than to consider all the possible subsets of a given size.  Of course there are some helpful symmetries, and for large $j$ you can work from the complement, but it's still messy.  There are effectively seven balls, and $\binom 74=35$ after all.

Comment: You can best exploit the symmetries by counting how many of the $\frac 1{10}$ balls are chosen, then how many of the $\frac 2{10}$ balls.

Comment: @lulu, Respected Mr. lulu, please, provide the detailed answer to this problem. Thank you!

Comment: @VadimChernetsov  It's very messy.  There are $2^7=128$ possible subsets, though you can cut that down with symmetry.  Not sure it helps that much...I'd probably just automate the thing.  Run all $2^7$ and then sum up according to the size of the subsets.  I don't think the computation would be terribly informative...

Answer (score 0):

Probability is defined for a specific outcome. Choosing $j$ balls is an experiment rather than an outcome. You can ask probability for an outcome like first ball being ball-1 and second ball being ball-7, etc. I don't understand what you exactly mean when you say probability of choosing $j$ balls.